# Jade Plant Black/Brown Roots: Is it normal?

Tags: roots, jade

I have this relatively small jade plant and I was going to repot it, but when I took it out of its original pot the roots were dark brown, the same color as the soil its in. I am used to roots being white or light brown, are these dark roots normal? [image]

I am sorry about the bad photo, otherwise the plant seems to be doing fine.

[image]

Comment: Since we can't see the plant, please confirm you mean Crassula ovata when you say jade plant, or post a picture of the whole plant.  And you're right, its next to impossible to see roots in your photo,

Comment: I added a picture of the plant, it is a crassula ovata.I tried to take more photos but this was the best one. The roots really blend in.